# Vagrant synced folder permission issue with apache

Tags: apache, permissions, centos, vagrant

I'm running a Centos6.4 box.

Running `vagrant up` without the synced folder config in Vagrant file is fine. I can access on my host machine via `http://localhost:8080` and it displays the Apache page. I could create index.html in `/var/www/html` folder and it displays fine too.

However after adding the line below in the Vagrant file, visiting the page displays `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.` error instead:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./source", "/var/www/html", :extra=>"dmode=777,fmode=777"
```

Going into the VM I see the permission set as below in `/var/www`:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root    root    4.0K Jul 20 23:15 .
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root    root    4.0K Jul 20 23:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root    4.0K May 14 06:12 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root    root    4.0K Jul 20 23:15 error
drwxrwxrwx.  1 vagrant vagrant  102 Jul 21 23:14 html
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root    root    4.0K Jul 20 23:18 icons
```

So I tried setting apache ownership to it,

```
   config.vm.synced_folder "./source", "/var/www/html", :owner=>"apache",:group=>"apache",:extra=>"dmode=777,fmode=777"
```

but that doesn't work too.

Apparently it has full read/write permissions and I have no clue why apache is complaining.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Figure out the user/group which runs httpd, make sure the user has execute permission on `/var/www` and its subfolders.**

Also, in you apache site configuration files, make sure you have correct directives for `/var/www`, something like below

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**Disable SELinux in the guest, it's useless to a development env**

Edit `/etc/selinux/config`

Change SELINUX to disabled

`SELINUX=disabled`

Reboot the vagrant box => `vagrant reload`

See if #1 with #2 helps.

Comment: I set `SELINUX=disabled` and repackaged it. It works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear it's fixed. Sure enough, SELinux again;-)

Comment: SELINUX=disabled and reloading vagrant worked for me with Vagrant/Centos7. Thanks!