# How do I disable default /vagrant mount or project directory?

Tags: vagrantfile

Here is my Vargrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.provision  :shell, path: "vagarantAddUser.sh"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/web", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
end
```

I want to mount my project directory (the directory on host from which I run `vagrant up`) at /web in guest instead of the default /vagrant. The above Vagrantfile mounts the project directory to both /vagrant and /web. Commenting out the synced_folder line for /vagrant has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue (and others related to mount permissions) was due to SELINUX set to enforcing. Adding `sudo sed -i 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/' /etc/selinux/config` to provisioning make all issues disappear. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773963/vagrant-synced-folder-permission-issue-with-apache)